# When I open a COM port some pins on Arduino Uno goes low for about 2 seconds

Tags: serial

I have no idea why this is happening, but after I open COM port to talk with my Arduino (I click "Open" in RealTerm), the state of some pins goes from high to low for about 2 seconds and then goes back to high. Here's my code:

```
void setup()
{
  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
}
```

In this case pin 5 will behave this way. I've checked it also for pin 6 and pin 8 and they behave in the same manner. I suppose more pins act like that. Why is this happening?

Comment: That's because opening the connection to the UNO will automatically trigger a reset of the ATmega chip, hence your sketch will be executed from scratch, ie `setup()` will be called again then `loop()`.

Comment: @jfpoilpret you should put that as an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see is expected: that's because opening the USB connection to the UNO will automatically trigger a reset of the ATmega chip of the board, hence your sketch will be executed from scratch, ie `setup()` will be called again then your `loop()` repeatedly.

Hence what you observe in detail:

1. open USB connection from PC
2. open USB connection on Arduino UNO
3. UNO USB chip (an ATmega16u2) triggers a RESET of the MCU (an ATmega328P-PU)
4. On reset, the MCU sets all pins to INPUT, i.e. high impedence, **hence no voltage can be measured on any pin**
5. Then the bootloader starts, performs some intialization and starts your sketch
6. Your sketch executes first `setup()`, so your pin is put in OUTPUT mode and set to HIGH: **its voltage is thus measurable (5V)**
7. your sketch `loop()` gets executed "forever" i.e.until a new reset or power supply disconnection

Comment: Indeed.  Worth noting though is that this reset-on-open is ultimately due to a configurable behavior of how the PC operating system's serial API manages the control lines - though this is usual default.  Additionally, it can be disabled at the arduino end by overpowering the reset capacitor with a stronger pullup.

Comment: What is the logic behind resetting upon connection? What exactly happens when I click "Open"?

Comment: That is because the bootloader must be started in order to check if connection was open in order to upload a new sketch. This is because USB can be used for both situations: upload a sketch, or just communicate with the running sketch.

Answer (score 0):

The arduino is reseting because of the serial port initializing. If you want to avoid it, you can put a 120 ohm resistor between 5v and reset.

[Source](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection)